# How do I dry up a stucco wall that presents efflorescence?

Tags: insulation, basement

I have determined the source of the water and I would like to believe that I stopped that with a temporary fix (a large tarp that will cover my patio which used to collect water at the base of the wall; I am on my way to redo the patio as well).
Now, because the temperatures are getting below 0 here where I live I would like to speed up the drying of this wall (see the picture below)
I would like to try that from inside and from outside if there is any way to do it.
Outside is what you see in the picture below
Inside is a finished basement with above the grade windows. I am quite sure that the previous owner used a vapor barrier right under the drywall and fiberglass insulation (so it is solid insulation panels,2x4 studs, fiberglass, vapor barrier and drywall)
Is there any way to dry up that wall from inside without tearing down the whole thing and rebuilding it?
From what I have read so far I will need to rebuild it because a plastic vapour barier is the last thing that you need in these cases. The same for the fiber glass batt that absorbs water and adders to the wall making the things even worse
[image] 
Edit: this is 9 months later. I fixed the slope of the patio 1 month ago, and while I was fixing that I realized that a lot of water was going under the patio via the deck post holes around which the patio was also poorly sloped. I found dirt and earthworms under the bricks ... 
My brother in low told me that it will take year for the humidity in soil to disappear ...I am more optimistic but he might be right. Here is a picture taken today (~9 months later)
[image]

Comment: The seasons have cycled considerably by now.  Did you successfully stop the source of the moisture?  Were you able to dry the brick?  Did the efflorescence stop?

Comment: I just posted an update, see above. Also see my other messages around here.. for the long story

Answer (score 1):

Here's what comes to mind:

- Increasing air flow, using fans - on both sides if possible.
- Applying a product that will extract the moisture (sorry, no idea if such a product exists - maybe someone else knows of one).
- Increasing the heat of the area to encourage moisture evaporation.  This can be accomplished with conventional heaters, heating bars, or using mirrors to redirect the sunlight.

Combining the ideas may increase their efficacy.

Please note that I do not consider myself to be an expert on this matter.

Comment: thanks, these are commons sense solutions that I considered too. If you are familiar with how the insulating is done you will ralize that none of the above is easily applicable from inside for a finished basement>
Whatch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2FVvvtISEX8 This solution is cost prohibitive. The cost of removeing the drywall and installing it back is much lower than buying this. I wonder if this could be improvised with a regular dehumidifier http://www.sycorp.ca/restoration/injectidry-drying-systems/

Comment: @user2059078 I agree!  Mostly common sense (except the mirror idea) to me as well.  Although sometimes what is common sense to one person is genius to another. :-)  I have no problem at all deleting the answer if there is nothing new to you in there; just let me know.  I have no ego attachments to it!  I like your idea of a dehumidifier as well.  Maybe you can combine that on the inside, with one or more of my ideas on the outside.  Also, I do seem to remember some sort of water-wicking product, but I just can't think of it right now.  Anyways, I gave your question an upvote to try to help!